# Inferring bounds from joint typicality on three variables

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, compression

Consider the following exercise from Cover and Thomas:

[image]

And the given solution from the solutions manual:

[image]

It is reasonably clear that these bounds are valid (one simply follows the counting argument given in the chapter, but applied to triple X,Y,Z instead of the pair X,Y). It is not clear to me, however, that these are the tightest bounds that can be found. In particular, it is immediately apparent that the pairwise typicality condition is not used in this solution. This seems strange, to me - does the inclusion of the pairwise typicality condition not provide us any information we can use to obtain narrower bounds? If not, why not - and would that imply that the inclusion of the pairwise typicality condition is in some sense unnecessary or redundant?

Comment: But the bounds are tight (up to the $\epsilon$s, which this technique can't get rid of anyway) - what exactly are you proposing to improve? As for which conditions were used, this should be obvious if you have understood the argument. As an exercise for this, try to do the calculation for the case when $(\tilde{X}^n, \tilde{Y}^n, \tilde{Z}^n) \sim P_{XY}^n \cdot P_Z^n$ (i.e., $(\tilde X,\tilde Y)$ is drawn independently of $\tilde Z$, and all the laws are the same). Which conditions do you use? Are they different from the ones in this solution? Why are they different?

Comment: Thanks!  The suggested exercise makes the role of the pairwise conditions apparent.

Comment: Nice. You're welcome. I suggest that you write an answer to this question (and accept it) - this can serve as reference to someone else that might have a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pairwise conditions are "not useful" merely in the sense that the problem is not asking about a situation that they control. The problem asks us only about the case where the variables are drawn totally independently.  The pairwise conditions control other, similar scenarios - such as when X and Y are drawn together, but (jointly) independently of Z.